# React.js render subcomponents from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a reusable component where the DOM structure can be different each time the component is rendered. Let's say I have this

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            click: null,
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.chidren}
            </div>
        )
    }
    handleButton1() {
        this.setState({click: 'button1'});
    }
    handleButton2() {
        this.setState({click: 'button2'});
    }
}
class SubComp1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleButton1()}>Button 1</button>
        )
    }
}
class SubComp2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleButton2()}>Button 2</button>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render((
<Comp>
    <div id="somediv">
        <div id="andanother">
            <SubComp1 />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="andanotherother">
        <SubComp2 />
    </div>
</Comp>), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Currently, the two subcomponents do **not** have access to their respective handler functions. What's the best way of passing the functions `handleButton1` and `handleButton2` to the subcomponents assuming that their position in the DOM is dynamic and might change depending on the layout of the page. 
I have thought of 2 solutions so far:

1. Iterating inside the `props.children` until I find the element of interest then clone it with the property
2. Using `ref` and somehow render the subcomponents after the main component has been rendered through the `componentDidMount` callback.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Could you highlight your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a place where using React's [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) would be the most straightforward solution.

Another solution would be to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) actions, but that would make your component less reusable and more tightly coupled with your application, which you may or may not care about.

Comment: (The first example in the linked React Context documentation should tell you enough about how to go about implementing it)

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a working solution. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I also figured out another solution involving passing the instance of the components to the subcomponents but it required some trick. This worked exactly as expected, thanks!

Comment: @BinyuanSun Glad to know that

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            click: null,
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.chidren}
            </div>
        )
    }
    handleButton(button) {
        this.setState({click: button});
    }
}
```

Then in the subcomponents you can do something like

```
class SubComp1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleButton('button1')}>Button 1</button>
        )
    }
}

class SubComp2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => this.props.handleButton('button2')}>Button 2</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: By doing that, does the subcomponents have access to the `this.props.handleButton` from the parent?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, in that case using `React.cloneElement` with the appropriate props seems like a good option.

Comment: But the problem would be that it might have to loop through it a lot before finding the desirable element, depending on the level of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

One Alternative option which might fit your needs is to build a higher order component, which decorates another component with some additional functionality, below is a quick example of how this may work for you,

The higher order component:

```
const Comp = ComposedComponent =>
  class Comp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            click: null,
        }
    }

    handleButton(button) {
      this.setState({click: button}); 
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ComposedComponent
              onClick={this.handleButton}
            />
        )
    }
  }

  export default Comp;
```

The child component:

```
class SubComp1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick('button1')}>Button 1</button>
        )
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
const ExtendedComp = Comp(SubComp1);

<ExtendedComp />
```

would this be suitable for your task?

Comment: If I was to do `const ExtendedComp1 = Comp(SubComp1);` and `const ExtendedComp2 = Comp(SubComp2);`, would they be modifying the same `state.click`?

Comment: No because they are separate instances, the higher order component simply takes a component as a parameter and extends its functionality. Generally the state in react should be related to the ui, and if you intend on having many different components accessing a global state throughout your application maybe you should consider using a state management library such as redux or mobX